# Display an error message on standard page

Tags: custom-button, page-layout, adderror

I have a class which i called from a custom button to send the record for approval. Before sending the record for approval I need to validate the record values and if any error is there I want to display it on standard page of the record. For this I have sobjectname.addError(). But is throwing a error :-

> System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

My code :-

```
global class SpecialPricingApproved_Controller{

webService static string SpecialPricingApproved_Request(ID oppid){

    List<opportunity> oppList = new List<opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity oppResult : [SELECT OwnerId, Manager_of_Manager__c, Max_Discount__c FROM opportunity WHERE ID = :oppid]){
        if(oppResult.Max_Discount__c == 10.00 || oppResult.Max_Discount__c == null){

            Opportunity oppError = new Opportunity();
            oppError = oppResult;
            oppError.addError('Max discount should be greater than 10 % for Approval');

            return null;
        }


        if(oppResult.Manager_of_Manager__c == null){
            oppList.add(oppResult);
            Opportunity_Helper.addManagerofManager(oppList, true);
        }
    }

    //Sending record for approval 
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Submitted for Approval');
    req1.setObjectId(oppid);
    Approval.ProcessResult res = Approval.Process(req1);   

    return null;

}
}
```

My error :

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was
>   encountered:{faultcode:'soapenv:Client',
>   faultstring:'System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors 
>   Class.SpecialPricingApproved_Controller.SpecialPricingApproved_Request:
>   line 22, column 1', }

Line no 22 is :

```
oppError.addError('Max discount should be greater than 10 % for Approval');
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error.

Comment: Can you please refer below link?
http://srinivas4sfdc.blogspot.in/2013/12/systemexception-sobject-row-does-not.html

Comment: Can we show error message as javascript alert?

Comment: @PankajGanwani made the changes as per refer link. But getting the same error.

Comment: @PankajGanwani updated my code with error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things.

1)  Return the result back to your javascript button.

```
var result = myJSWebcallhere();
if (result != '')
  alert(result);
```

2) catch the errors in your service and return them as the result.

```
webService static string SpecialPricingApproved_Request(ID oppid)
{
  try
  {
    List<opportunity> oppList = new List<opportunity>();
    Opportunity errorHandler = new Opportunity();

    oppList = [SELECT OwnerId, Manager_of_Manager__c, Max_Discount__c FROM opportunity WHERE ID = :oppid];      

    if(oppList.size() > 0){
      if(oppList[0].Max_Discount__c == 10.00 || oppList[0].Max_Discount__c == null){
        return 'Max discount should be greater than 10 % for Approval';
      }

      if(oppList[0].Manager_of_Manager__c == null){
        Opportunity_Helper.addManagerofManager(oppList, true);
      }
    }

    //Sending record for approval 
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Submitted for Approval');
    req1.setObjectId(oppid);
    Approval.ProcessResult res = Approval.Process(req1);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return 'Error = ' + e.getMessage());
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: made the changes as per your code getting error : A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @Anu I forgot, Javascript doesn't use 'String'.  It uses 'Var'.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do the validation in the apex class, do it on the page button itself.

Just call the class for Approval process execution.

Class should be like

```
Public class Class Name{


webService static void SpecialPricingApproved_Request(ID oppid)

{

    List<opportunity> oppList = new List<opportunity>();
    Opportunity errorHandler = new Opportunity();

    oppList = [SELECT OwnerId, Manager_of_Manager__c, Max_Discount__c FROM opportunity WHERE ID = :oppid];         

      if(oppList[0].Manager_of_Manager__c == null){
        Opportunity_Helper.addManagerofManager(oppList, true);
      }
    }

    //Sending record for approval 
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Submitted for Approval');
    req1.setObjectId(oppid);
    Approval.ProcessResult res = Approval.Process(req1);

}

}
```

Button should have

```
var x ='{!Max_Discount__c}';

if(x==10||x==null){
alert('errormessage');
}
```

call apex method using sforce.apex.execute and pass id to the method as you did